# React-Native 0.60.5 Crash on Launch (Android)

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a production app which we recently integrated react-native into. We tested the app and didn't find any issues with the react-native elements but upon release we are getting multiple crash reports related to `libhwui.so` and `libc.so`. I'm convinced its a react-native problem.

```
 #00  pc 0000000000092bc4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
  #01  pc 0000000000091ccc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
  #02  pc 0000000000091524  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
  #03  pc 0000000000033cb8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
  #04  pc 00000000000366a4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
  #05  pc 000000000003c5a0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+152)
  #06  pc 0000000000012448  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+272)
  #07  pc 00000000000a2218  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+128)
  #08  pc 000000000006a3c4  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
  #09  pc 000000000001dc28  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

This only occurs on specific devices (All running android 7) which we don't have, thus can't reproduce. These users can't open the app at all due to this error. Initially we began work with react 0.59.9, some other posts with a similar problem suggested to upgrade to 0.60.5 (latest at this time), this reduced the number of users affected, but the crash is still occurring. I think it could be something to do with the version of js being used? I've upgraded to v8 by adding a node dependency and adding it to the android manifest as outlined [here](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-v8), but the problem still persists.

Affected devices include: Sony Xperia L1 (G3311), Samsung Galaxy A3 (2017) (a3y17lte).

We deploy to both iOS and Android and this issue only occurs on android.

Here is some extra information about my environment and the project if its helpful.

minSdkVersion: 21,
targetSdkVersion: 28,
compileSdkVersion 28,
minifyEnabled: true,
buildToolsVersion: 28.0.3.

From searching around it seems to be any number of issues varying from garbage collection to issues with the react-native bridge.

Have other people encountered this issue?

Any ideas on what might be the cause of this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I solved this issue for the most part by doing three things. 1. Updating to react-native v0.60.5. 2. Changing from using android-jsc to chromes v8 javascript core. 3. updating the ndk abi filters. Now down to only 1 device crashing due to react-native.

Comment: we met it in only android 6 devices with RN 0.60.6.

Comment: @CiaránCoady what did you end up using for your ndk abi filters that helped with this issue?